# how to access class of an interface after implementing it and instantiating that concrete class?

Tags: java

There is a class nutrition within an interface forboth which is implemented by another class Rose. How can I access the methods of class nutrition by instantiating Rose?

```
 interface forboth {
    void habitat();
    int i = 2;
    static class nutrition {
        static void water() { System.out.println("m in water"); }
        void manure() {};
    }
}

class Rose implements forboth {
    @Override
public void habitat() {}
}

class RoseLotus {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rose rose = new Rose();
        Lotus lotus = new Lotus();
        int j = rose.i;
        rose.nutrition.water();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please use an IDE with autoformatting.

Comment: @Christian In the OP's defense, new users frequently have difficulty convincing SO's code blocks to format copy + pasted code properly. Editing the post to format the code for them is helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nutrition` class is a [nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of `forboth`, not of `Rose`.

```
forboth.nutrition.water();
```

Java doesn't pass nested classes in interfaces down into implementing class namespaces, to alleviate potential issues from inheriting multiple interfaces.

It is traditional Java naming convention to start classes with capital letters, by the way. It's not required, of course, but it will make your code more readable to others (and it won't confuse the syntax highlighter on SO).

Comment: but being implemented by Rose cant i access that class with the instance of class Rose

Comment: No. Java doesn't pass nested classes in interfaces down into implementing class namespaces, to alleviate potential issues from inheriting multiple interfaces.